# Probability proof with independent events

Tags: probability

If events $A_1,...A_n$ are independent (in total), show that $$P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i\right)=1-\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-P(A_i)\right).$$

Could someone show how to prove this statement?

Comment: This user has submitted 5 homework-type questions with no context/effort in the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

Here a verbal proof: the left-handed side represents the probability that *at least one* of the events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ occurs. The quantity $1-P(A_i)$ represents the probability that $A_i$ does *not* occur, and by independence the product represents the probability that *none* of the events occurs. Thus, both sides represent the same probability.